# Calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\delta(x^4+(\alpha-x)^4-(\alpha-\alpha_1)^4-\alpha_1^4)dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

i want to calculate
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\delta(x^4+(\alpha-x)^4-(\alpha-\alpha_1)^4-\alpha_1^4)dx,$$
where $\alpha$ and $\alpha_1$ indenpent of $x$. can anyone give me some suggetions?

Answer (score 1):

There is a formula here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

($x^4+(\alpha-x)^4-(\alpha-\alpha_1)^4-\alpha_1^4$ has only simple roots?)

[image]

Comment: Yes, but there may be two image roots, i do not know whether the image roots should be counted?

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\alpha-\alpha_1$ are real roots, if the other roots are imaginary (ignore them in the formula) then each root has multiplicity one (because the degree of this polynomial is 4)

Answer (score 0):

To use the integration formula given by @Blah, you need to find the roots of the polynomial
$$p(x)=x^4+(\alpha-x)^4-(\alpha-\alpha_1)^4-\alpha_1^4.$$
Note that these roots are easy to guess without entering any complex algebraic machinery. For instance $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha-\alpha_1$ are roots of $p$. $p$ has degree of $4$, so there are two other roots in the general case. 
We have
$$p(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha+\alpha_1)\times 2 (x^2-\alpha x+\alpha_1^2-2\alpha\alpha_1+2\alpha^2). $$
Let us consider $q(x)=x^2-\alpha x+\alpha_1^2-2\alpha\alpha_1+2\alpha^2$. Its discriminant is $\Delta_1=-3\alpha^2-8\alpha\alpha_1-4\alpha_1^2$. As a polynomial in $\alpha$, $\Delta_1$ has discriminant $\Delta_\alpha=(8^2-4\times3\times4)\alpha_1^2$.

- If $\alpha_1\neq0$ $\Delta_\alpha<0$ so the sign of $\Delta_1$ does not change for different values of $\alpha$. So it means that $\Delta_1<0$ and therefore the two other roots of $p$ have a non zero imaginary part.  The solution if therefore $f(\alpha_1)/|p'(\alpha_1)|+f(\alpha-\alpha_1)/|p'(\alpha-\alpha_1)|$.
- If $\alpha_1=0$, $\Delta_\alpha=0$ and $\Delta_1=0$ if $\alpha=0$.

  - If $\alpha\neq0$ then $\Delta_1<0$ and the above formula applies.
  - If $\alpha=0$, then you are computing $\int f(x)\delta(2x^4)\mathrm d x$.
    Changing the variable $x^4$ might give the solution if $f(x)=O(x^3)$ when 
    $x\to0$.